# Finding average of numbers excluding -1

Tags: python, average

> Write a program that continually asks the user to enter a number.
>
> - When the user enters “-1”, the program should stop requesting the user
>   to enter a number,
> - The program must then calculate the average of the numbers entered,
>   excluding the -1.
> - Make use of the while loop repetition structure to implement the
>   program.

What I have done so far is the first part. Struggling with second part

```
random_num = 0

while True:
    print(random_num)

    random_num = input("enter a number: ")
    if random_num == "-1":
        break
```

Comment: cast the random_num as a int (use the int() function), then you can start processing it, then calculate the average by computing the sum and the amt of numbers entered

Comment: What do you mean by "struggling"? You didn't write any code that tries to calculate the average. It looks more like you are asking us to do your homework for you. That's probably why you get downvoted. You may want to check [ask].